# Why Dirac deltas at $\pm1$ are solutions of the ODE $\left( 1-x^2 \right) y'' - 4xy' -2y = 0$ on $[-1,1]$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, boundary-value-problem

I'm trying to reproduce the calculations of a paper. The goal is to solve the following ODE: $\left( 1-x^2 \right) y'' - 4xy' + (c-2)y = 0$, inside the interval $[-1,1]$. The solution must be normalizable, i.e., $\int y(x)dx < \infty$.

For $c = 0$, they say that the solution can be considered as a sum of two delta functions $\delta(x-1)$ and $\delta(x+1)$. But as far as I know, the delta functions make sense when integrated, i.e., $f(x_0) = \int f(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx$. So, **what is the reasoning behind this solution, how does one find this solution and how to check if it's a solution of the equation**, since I don't know how to take the derivative of a delta.

For $c>0$, they say that the solution is $y_c(x) = a_+\delta(x-1) + a_-\delta(x+1) + \phi_c(x)\theta(x+1)\theta(x-1)$, being $a_+$ and $a_-$ constants and $\theta(x)$ the Heavisde function. They plug this ansatz in the original equation and find an equal one but for the function $\phi_c$. What happened with the $\delta$s? Besides, they claim that there are now two extra conditions $\lim_{ x\rightarrow \pm 1} \phi_c = - \frac{c}{2} a_{\pm}$. My question here is **how to plug all these non-derivable functions in the original ODE and why this extra condition is necessary**. Thanks!

All this treatment with delta functions is surprising to me and before entering to solve explicitly for $\phi_c(x)$ I wanted a bit of comprehension.

Comment: The $n$th derivative of the Dirac delta can be readily understood in the sense of distribution theory: $\delta^{(n)}(f)=(-1)^n f^{(n)}(0)$. Thus for instance "$(1-x^2)\delta''(x-1)-4x\delta'(x-1)-2\delta(x-1)$ is a distribution which maps a function $f$ to $\left. \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(f(x)(1-x^2)) \right |_{x=1} + 4 \left. \frac{d}{dx} (xf(x)) \right |_{x=1}-2f(1)$. The situation here looks weird because of the $(1-x^2)$ multiplying the leading order derivative, since that vanishes at both boundaries.